# Keyboard shortcut select the clicked word

Tags: adobe-brackets

In Brackets, is it possible to assign a keyboard shortcut to CTRL + LMB that selects the clicked word, just like Visual Studio does? I can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding the click behavior would require [writing an extension](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Write-Extensions), but there are several built-in equivalents that might be good enough for you:

1. Press Ctrl-B to select the word the cursor is on 
   (you can easily [change the shortcut](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/User-Key-Bindings) but it has to be triggered by the keyboard, not the mouse)
2. Double-click to select the word
3. In your [preferences file](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#preferences), add `"highlightMatches": {"showToken": true}` to highlight all occurrences of any word you place your cursor on (no need to select it)